# R function for finding sum of intervals in a vector mysteriously returns numeric(0), but works fine manually

Tags: r, function

I made the following function for finding the sum of all the intervals in a  sorted numeric vector:

```
sum.intervals <- function(x){
        x <- sort(x)
        acc <- 0
        for( i in 1:length(x) - 1 ){
            acc <- acc + x[i + 1] - x[i]
        }
        return(acc)
    }
```

When trying to use it, I expect a scalar value, but instead get `numeric(0)`:

```
x <- c(5, 2, 7, 3)
y <- sum.intervals(x)
y
#numeric(0)
```

However, when performing the iterations manually the idea works fine:

```
x <- sort(x)
acc <- 0

i <- 1
acc <- acc + x[i + 1] - x[i]

i <- 2
acc <- acc + x[i + 1] - x[i]

i <- 3
acc <- acc + x[i + 1] - x[i]

acc
#5
```

What is wrong with the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1:length(x) - 1` should be `1:(length(x) - 1)`. You are subtracting 1 from every element in the vector.

Comment: Yep, and that means on the first iteration you end up trying to access `x[0]`, which gives an empty vector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a loop here? Just do:

```
 sum(diff(sort(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without a loop as well

```
sum( x[-1] - x[-length(x)])
#[1] 5
```